# Mocking $.fn.find with Jasmine seems to have magic behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, tdd, jasmine

I’m writing a method that’s a simple wrapper around calls to $.fn.modal. The method takes a selector and that selector should be passed to jQuery, so jQuery can *find* an element matching that selector.

Here’s what my spec looks like:

```js
describe('The modal presenter', function() {

  it('operates on the provided selector', function() {
    spyOn($.fn, 'find');
    myModule.presentModal('#the-modal', {});
    expect($.fn.find).toHaveBeenCalledWith('#the-modal');
  });

});
```

This is all fine. The odd behaviour is happening in my production code.

```js
var myModule = {
  presentModal: function(selector, event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(selector, document).modal('show'); // This line works
    $(document).find(selector).modal('show'); // This line doesn’t work?!

    // This should be fairly obvious, but I’m not running both
    // of the above lines at the same time. I comment one out
    // and run the method with one line at a time.
  }
}
```

As far as I’m aware, those two lines that I’ve added comments to should be equivalent. They should both call `$.fn.find` with `selector`. The second commented line should *definitely* call `.find`, as I’ve written that explicitly.

When I run my test, I get `TypeError: $(...).find(...) is undefined`. How could this be?

Comment: I’ve just realised that in order to make the second `.find()` call work, I need to change my mock to `spyOn($.fn, 'find').and.callThrough();`. If someone would like to give a more detailed answer that explains *why* it works this way, go right ahead; free points for you :)